# Join query taking more time compared to query with sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query with sub-query which takes around 10 mins of time for execution so I thought of writing the same logic using JOIN to get results faster. But eventually the JOIN query is taking much more time compared to the sub-query.

**Using sub-query**

```
select count(distinct nrc_app_no) from nrc_doc_submit_tbl 
where ng_status='Uploaded' 
and (processed_by is null OR processed_by='XML1')
and nrc_app_no not in 
(
  select distinct nrc_app_no from nrc_doc_submit_tbl where ng_status='Parsed'
)
and 
(
   nrc_app_no not like '4%' and
   nrc_app_no not like '5%' and
   nrc_app_no not like '6%'
);
```

**Plan :**
[image]

**Using JOIN & substr**

```
select count(distinct a.nrc_app_no)
from 
   nrc_doc_submit_tbl a left join nrc_doc_submit_tbl b
on 
   a.nrc_app_no=b.nrc_app_no and b.ng_status='Parsed' and a.ng_status='Uploaded' 
   and (a.processed_by is null OR  a.processed_by='XML1')
where 
  b.nrc_app_no is null and substr(a.nrc_app_no,1,1) not in ('4','5','6');
```

**Plan** :
[image]

**Database**   : Oracle 11g

**Table size** : 10  million rows

I have also attached plans for both the queries.

**Primary key** : NRC_APP_NO , FAMILY_MEMBER_ID , NRC_DOC_SUBMIT_ID

List of Indexes :
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide the layout of the tables, particularly indexes and primary keys.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I have attached indexes' list and also mentioned primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to use a self-join or a correlated sub-query as you can get the same functionality with an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) (which will only require a single table scan):

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT nrc_app_no )
FROM   (
  SELECT nrc_app_no,
         ng_status,
         processed_by,
         COUNT( CASE ng_status WHEN 'Parsed' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY nrc_app_no ) AS parsed_count
  FROM   nrc_doc_submit_tbl
)
WHERE  ng_status    = 'Uploaded'
AND    (processed_by is null OR processed_by='XML1')
AND    parsed_count = 0
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '4%'
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '5%'
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '6%';
```

**Alternative - Not Exists**:

Back to two table (or index) scans:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT nrc_app_no )
FROM   nrc_doc_submit_tbl a
WHERE  ng_status    = 'Uploaded'
AND    (processed_by is null OR processed_by='XML1')
AND    NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 'X'
                    FROM   nrc_doc_submit_tbl b
                    WHERE  a.nrc_app_no = b.nrc_app_no
                    AND    b.ng_status  = 'Parsed'
                  )
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '4%'
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '5%'
AND    nrc_app_no   NOT LIKE '6%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @MT0

Comment: when i am your query it throwing an error saying invalid identifier for nrc_app_no in the last line. The query inside from clause is running fine. And even I used alias name for the query inside from clause but again the same error is appearing.

Comment: @SagarJoon Updated - was missing a comma

Comment: your query is taking twice the time taken by subquery.

Comment: @SagarJoon added an alternative using `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the first one by changing this:

```
and nrc_app_no not in 
(
select distinct nrc_app_no from nrc_doc_submit_tbl where ng_status='Parsed' 
)
```

to this:

```
and nrc_app_no in 
(
select nrc_app_no from nrc_doc_submit_tbl
minus
select nrc_app_no from nrc_doc_submit_tbl 
where ng_status='Parsed'
)
```

`not in` is slow.

Also slow is filtering on function results.  You have this:

```
and substr(a.nrc_app_no,1,1) not in ('4','5','6')
```

Using the syntax of your first query might be better.

Comment: Using `IN` and `MINUS` are you not then doing an extra table scan (or index scan) and is that really faster than using `NOT IN`? Can you provide a reference to back up the performance claims as I would like to read more about it?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dan Bracuk

Comment: @MT0, this technique is very unintuitive, but it works.  My reference is the results I get.  I could put together an example, but then again, so could you.